# Kids SF TV show: kid gets a laser as a gift and uses it to solve mysteries

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to remember the name of a kids TV show I saw in the early 1980's. It was shown in the UK probably on the BBC but may have been channel 3.

The story was this: a kid gets a laser as a gift (I know, it makes as much sense as Donald Trump's hair!) and uses it to solve mysteries and if I recall correctly rescue some kidnapped kids. The laser is basically a neon light in a wooden box that the kid carries on a shoulder strap. It can zap people and freeze them and it talks to the kid. The final scene was a heartbreaker. While the kid is sleeping the laser announces it has run out of power and will turn itself off forever. Before it dies it draws a heart in the air.

This was not a British show. I clearly recall that it was dubbed. Can anyone tell me the title or point me to some information about it please? Thank you.

Comment: was it live action? this is possible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_(TV_series)

Comment: Yes, It was live action. Apologies should have said that. Sadly it's not Photon. I also should have mentioned that it was dubbed from a european language. I have a suspicion that it was dutch but it could as easily have been german or french. Anyway, definitely eurpoean so hat might help narrow it down. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [Oskar, Kina and the Laser](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076967/).  It's a Spanish show from the late 1970s that was shown in the UK dubbed into English.  [TV Cream](http://www.tvcream.co.uk/?p=1686) has a page for it.

Oskar makes his own laser rather than getting it as a gift, but he does carry it around in a wooden box.  It talks to him and he has adventures with it (which for some reason include a goose called Kina).  The show ends when the laser runs out of power and shuts down.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you! As soon as you mentioned the goose it all came back! Didn't recall that he made the laser but it must be thirty years since I've seen it! Brilliant!