# (Probably) Russian movie or TV series about a boy who makes sentient laser device which talks to him

Tags: story-identification

I saw it in Czechoslovakia probably in the mid 80s.

It was probably Russian (I think people had Russian names, but I'm not sure - I was 6-7 at the time).

It was set in 1960-80s (technology didn't seem too old to me back then) and probably in some Soviet-bloc country (because surroundings didn't seemed weird to me back then).

I can't tell if it was in color or B&W because our family had only B&W TV back then.

The story was roughly this: a quite normal (but probably above average in intelligence) young boy (7-12 years old) built "The Laser" (it was a box which could be opened - size cca 15x15x30 cm / 6x6x12 in) and then realizes that "The Laser" "talks" to him (possibly by telepathy) and he gets into some "adventures" with him. And I'm almost sure he called it "My Friend Laser" or something like this and treated it as a friend or a mentor.

"The Laser" is clearly "the smart one", but I think he was also "robotically stupid" - i.e. it's asking why the boy needs to sleep or eat and similar stuff (this is only for explanation - I don't really recall questions about sleeping or eating - but it was in this "I am 100% logical and humans are a mystery to me" manner)

I think one of the episodes was how he used "The Laser" to stop some robbery at one time  (although I'm almost sure it was *not* by shooting the robbers), other may have been about some "evil scientists/Americans/?? who were trying to steal "The Laser" from him.
All episodes were probably this kind of silly "kid's adventures" stuff.

I think it was probably short series (but possibly longer and only some episodes were aired in Czechoslovakia at the time) but I can't rule out possibility of it being a movie.

At the time, it seemed to me like "ordinary story with some SF elements", but now it seems really bizarre to me and I'm starting to think that it's so silly it can't possibly be a real TV series.

Comment: So laser was not "shooting" at all ?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi I'm not really sure - but if it was, it was not really important for the story.. I know it sounds weird.. - The Laser was more "Alexa" or "Siri" than a weapon.... I think it was perhaps similar (concept of a thing doing quite different things than one would expect) to handling Virtual Reality in "The Lawnmower Man" movie (1922) - where VR was more of "oooh, it's MAGIC! It can do ANYTHING!" than as a mere visualization tool.. Perhaps at the time, Laser was seen as "magic" too..

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109374/kids-sf-tv-show-kid-gets-a-laser-as-a-gift-and-uses-it-to-solve-mysteries (about an English-dubbed BBC run of the series)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for [*Oscar, Kina and the Laser*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076967/) (AKA *Óscar, Kina y el láser*)

It certainly features a laser in a box, was a short run of episodes and made/broadcast at the time you mention.

I actually searched for this show too, so technically this question is a duplicate although I was hunting for a revoiced version shown on British TV in the early 1980s.

There are some clips on youtube...

Comment: YES! That's it - I was so young that I really didn't remember much, but this is it :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm really glad this is real and not a figment of my failing memory :)

Comment: I loved this as a kid, but it's totally insane.